# How to assert a Linq collection with unit test

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I have write simple group by with LinQ

```
public IList dividedNumbersto5(IEnumerable<int> NumberOfCollection)
{
    IList reminderNumber = NumberOfCollection.ToList().GroupBy(g => g%5).OrderBy(g=>g.Key)
        .Select(g => new { Numbers = g, Remindar = g.Key}).ToList();
    return reminderNumber;                              
}
```

When I try to test it , it says the first index item is not match with my expectation.

```
var groupingoperators = new GroupingOperators();
IEnumerable<int> numberOfCollection = new List<int>{ 5,14,9,8};
IList remindernumber = groupingoperators.dividedNumbersto5(numberOfCollection);
IList expectedNumberCollection = new List<int>{0,3,4};
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedNumberCollection, remindernumber);
```

> CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)

I wonder how should I write a test for it.

Comment: There's no way for this to pass.  You're returning a list of anonymous types and comparing it to a list of ints.

Comment: When you use `Remindar`, do you mean [`Remainder`](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remainder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your test fails is because of this:

```
   "Two collections are equal if they have the same elements 
   in the same order and quantity."
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx)

Basically you need to mock your second collection a little better. I think this should work:

```
IList expectedNumberCollection = new List<object>{
 new {Numbers = new List<int>{5},Remindar=0},
 new {Numbers = new List<int>{8},Remindar=3}, 
 new {Numbers = new List<int>{14,9},Remindar=4}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - **you really shouldn't return anonymous type objects from methods!** It's really hard to do anything with that kind of return values anywhere later.

I would create new struct called **Devided**:

```
public struct Devided
{
    public int Reminder { get; set; }
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(!(obj is Devided))
            return false;

        var d = (Devided)obj ;

        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, d))
            return true;

        return this.Reminder == d.Reminder && this.Numbers.SequenceEqual(d.Numbers);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Reminder;
    }
}
```

I've overridden  `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make `CollectionAssert` work.

With `Devided` class you can change your method return type to generic `IList<Devided>`:

```
public static IList<Devided> dividedNumbersto5(IEnumerable<int> NumberOfCollection)
{
    IList<Devided> reminderNumber = NumberOfCollection.ToList().GroupBy(g => g % 5).OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Select(g => new Devided { Numbers = g.ToList(), Reminder = g.Key }).ToList();
    return reminderNumber;
}
```

And assert testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numberOfCollection = new List<int> { 5, 14, 9, 8 };
    IList remindernumber = dividedNumbersto5(numberOfCollection);
    IList expectedNumberCollection = new List<Devided>
    {
        new Devided { Numbers = new List<int>() { 5 }, Reminder = 0 },
        new Devided { Numbers = new List<int>() { 8 }, Reminder = 3 },
        new Devided { Numbers = new List<int>() { 14, 9 }, Reminder = 4 }
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedNumberCollection, remindernumber);
}
```

You can check only `Reminder`s if you'd like to:

```
var expectedNumberCollection = new List<int> { 0, 3, 4 };

Assert.IsTrue(expectedNumberCollection.SequenceEqual(remindernumber.Select(x => x.Reminder)));
```